# Is there a textview-like console I can plug into my app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, logging, console

I'm debugging iBeacons, and this requires walking around to get in/out of range of them. I would like to print messages to a console to understand what's happening on the device. Because the development device is unplugged, NSLogging impossible. Right now I just have a TextView and am appending text to it.

```
-(void)postMessage:(NSString*)message
{
    self.textView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@",message,self.textView.text];
}
```

Is there a better way? Maybe some open source console that I can plug into a UIViewController and have it intercept messages I send to it and print them?

Comment: I think [iConsole](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iConsole) is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, this looks very promising!

Answer (score 1):

Using the console is NOT impossible. When you execute log statements, they get saved to the console log on the device, which you can then view in Xcode next time you connect the device to your Mac.

You could also add a scrolling text view to your window.

I suggest adding a mutable string property to your app. Create a logging singleton that has an addStringToLog method.

Use the NSMutableString appendString method to add the new message to your log.

You could either place a text view on your app's main window that gets updated with your log string, or create a log view controller that you invoke from a button.

NSLog has the advantage that it takes a format string and a variable number of parameters, and logs the contents. You need to use varargs if you want to do the same thing yourself. It's a little tricky, but possible.

Edit: You could also write your code so that it writes the logged text to a file in your documents directory, and then open the file in Xcode.